# lumen: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I am a beginner at lumen, which is somewhat based on laravel in php. I tried to create a lumen project using the command.

> lumen new blog

and received the following output in my terminal despite the folder being created:

```
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phar-io/manifest 1.0.1 -> satisfiable by phar-io/manifest[1.0.1].
    - phar-io/manifest 1.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.0.4].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 7.1.5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.1.5].
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.1.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.1.0].
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

I've come across similar questions while looking for answers almost none of them have any answers addressing the list of problems being displayed in the terminal despite having the correct version of php. Please help!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yep that fixed it. Ran - `sudo apt-get install php-xml` and it's working now. If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states:

> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

Install and enable the XML extension and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Certain extensions are missing in your php version . Check out the requirements and install them.

Comment: Why don't you tell which are missing? This should rather be a comment than an answer